# Issue with large value in Double variable in Excel VBA with Windows 10 LTSC

Tags: excel, vba, windows

A variable declared as Double caused Excel VBA to terminate function in Windows 10 LTSC. This code does NOT work:

`Dim Min As Double
Min = 1E+300
If (Min > MyVarA(2, I)) Then Min = MyVarA(2, I)`

No error message, function just termiates without any failure.

This code works in Windows 10 LTSB and other older Windows version like Win8.1 or Win7!

Solution to solve this issue: Reduce 1E+300 to 1E+30! This code works well:

`Dim Min As Double
Min = 1E+30
If (Min > MyVarA(2, I)) Then Min = MyVarA(2, I)`

Comment: If you can change the code to something else, without breaking your program, you may want to question whether the initial code was correct, or the substitute. To me it appears that neither does what you intended to do.

Answer (score 0):

*(Not enough points to just comment, so posting as an answer instead)*

VB/VBA is a little tricky in what it does under the hood when it comes to determing variable types. It tends to do data type conversions (*e.g. Double -> Single*), if it finds that doing so "optimizes" the code/execution.

Therefore it might help in forcing VBA to utilize the correct data type. This might be accomplished by the dedictated conversion methods such as CDbl(), CLng() etc. or by adding the type-declaration character (*e.g. '#' for Double, '&' for Long*) to the variable/value in question. In your case this might look like:

```
' Using type-declaration character '#' for Double
Min = 1E+300#
' Using data type conversion method CDbl()
If (Min > CDbl(MyVarA(2, I))) Then Min = CDbl(MyVarA(2, I))
```

All of the above ofc assumes that the actual data in question doesn't exceed the Double range.

Comment: Thanks for this comment which solved this issue much smarter than my simple workaround. This issue is obviously an Excel VBA type case failure which occured in combination with a new Windows 10 version!